# Force Redirect Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Ok, i need to force redirect `domain.com/article-detail/?slug=this-is-my-article` to `domain.com/article-detail/this-is-my-article` (just remove `?slug=`)

After searching in this site, i try

```
RewriteRule ^article-detail/?slug=(.*)$ article-detail/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Or

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/article-detail/?slug=(.+)$ /article-detail/$1/
```

But not working

FYI : Currently, to view `this-is-my-article` user can access `domain.com/article-detail/?slug=this-is-my-article` & `domain.com/article-detail/this-is-my-article`

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) directives.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/article-detail/?$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^slug=([a-z-]+)
RewriteRule ^article-detail /article-detail/%1/ [R=301,L]
```

Line 3: if the request URI is `/article-detail` or `/article-detail/`

Line 4: if the query string starting with `slug=` and followed by `lower case letters with dash`

Line 5: rewrite the pattern `article-detail` to `/article-detail/%1`, `%1` is `RewriteCond` backreference, matched the strings inside the parenthesis, and redirect permanently.